# .htaccess rewrite requests for file-name URLs to corresponding permalink URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a question about my .htaccess-code. It is doing the following:

1. Adding a trailing slash to every URL
2. Removing the .php file extension.

This works, so if I type `domain.com/page/`, the browser shows the content of `domain.com/page.php`. If I type `domain.com/page` (without the trailing slash), the browser redirects to `domain.com/page/`.

**BUT** if I type `domain.com/page.php` the browser does *not* redirect to `domain.com/page/`.

Is there a way to redirect the request `domain.com/page.php` to `domain.com/page/`?

Here's my current .htaccess-code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !(^$|\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^((/?[^/]+){1,2})/$ $1.php [L]
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.
Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##First 2 rules are added by OP itself.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !(^$|\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^((/?[^/]+){1,2})/$ $1.php [L]

##Newly added rule for removing .php from browser if .php is hit in it.
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works for me :) Only two questions:
1. If I request a file that does not exist, for example `domain.com/bla.php` it is also redirected to `domain.com/bla/` and then shows my 404 error page. Is this an issue? If it's returning a 404, it should not affect my SEO, right?
2. I can access folders with `domain.com/folder/` and with `domain.com/folder/index/` (`domain.com/folder/index.php` is redirected to the latter). Google should recognize that these two URLs are the same, especially if I declare a canonical URL, right?

Comment: @user15374596, IMHO you could handle it by Errordocument 404 rule simply redirect any 404 to a single document. Cheers.